# how to pass variable user.phone_number in left join select mysql query

Tags: mysql, left-join

this is my query.i want to pass user.phone_number variable in left join select query for order_botorder table which have limit 1

```
select
user.id as id,
user.updated_at as updated_at,
if(user.name is not null, user.name, "No Name") as name,
user.phone_number as phone_number,
user.created_at as member_since,
sum(if(offer_item.card_type="FIXED",offer.list_price,offer_item.custom_value)) as total_card_value,
sum(offer_item.redeemed_amount) as redeemed_amount,
if(offer_item.is_complete=0,count(offer_item.id),0) as active_gift_card,
bot_order.created_at
from account_firstuser as user
LEFT JOIN offer_offerorder as offer_order ON user.phone_number = offer_order.phone_number
LEFT JOIN offer_offeritem as offer_item ON offer_order.id = offer_item.offer_order_id
LEFT JOIN offer_offer as offer ON offer_item.offer_id = offer.id
LEFT JOIN (select * from order_botorder where store_id=1 and is_pos=0 and is_submitted=1 and phone_number=user.phone_number order by id desc limit 1) bot_order ON bot_order.phone_number = user.phone_number
where
user.store_id = 1 and
user.phone_number LIKE '%%' and
user.is_invalid = 0 and
user.is_blocked = 0
group by user.id,user.phone_number,offer_item.is_complete,bot_order.created_at
order by user.created_at
desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Its giving this error

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'user.phone_number' in 'where
> clause'

Comment: Could you share the schema of these tables?

Comment: [account_firstuser table](https://ibb.co/64F01F8)

[offer_offerorder table](https://ibb.co/GvRFW01)

[offer_offeritem table](https://ibb.co/Jk8hmMZ)

[offer_offer table](https://ibb.co/SvS9Rm5)

[order_botorder table](https://ibb.co/0c0qhVy)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. Debug questions require a [mre]. But after that pins down your problem & before you consider asking--[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097). [ask] [Help] Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please indent code reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-query is a completely separate space so if you need information from other tables you need to join again inside the sub-query.

I think you can just remove the `phone_number` condition in the sub-query, since you already join on this column and it should work correctly.

```sql
SELECT
    user.id as id,
    user.updated_at as updated_at,
    if(user.name is not null, user.name, "No Name") as name,
    user.phone_number as phone_number,
    user.created_at as member_since,
    bot_order.created_at
    sum(if(offer_item.card_type="FIXED",offer.list_price,offer_item.custom_value)) as total_card_value,
    sum(offer_item.redeemed_amount) as redeemed_amount,
    if(offer_item.is_complete=0,count(offer_item.id),0) as active_gift_card,
FROM account_firstuser as user
LEFT JOIN offer_offerorder as offer_order ON user.phone_number = offer_order.phone_number
LEFT JOIN offer_offeritem as offer_item ON offer_order.id = offer_item.offer_order_id
LEFT JOIN offer_offer as offer ON offer_item.offer_id = offer.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM order_botorder WHERE store_id=1 AND is_pos=0 AND is_submitted=1 order by id desc limit 1) bot_order ON bot_order.phone_number = user.phone_number
WHERE
    AND user.store_id = 1
    AND user.phone_number LIKE '%%'
    AND user.is_invalid = 0
    AND user.is_blocked = 0
GROUP BY user.id,user.phone_number,offer_item.is_complete, bot_order.created_at
ORDER BY user.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10 offset 0
```